# C++ vector insert with Iterator is not working as I expected

Tags: c++, vector, insert, iterator

C++11, Input is `nums = [1,2,3,4,5]`

```
void rotate(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
    nums.insert(nums.begin(), nums.end() - k, nums.end());
}
```

When `k = 2`, I expect this function should make nums to `[4,5,1,2,3,4,5]`
but it becomes `[2,3,1,2,3,4,5]`
When `k = 1`, nums is `[4,1,2,3,4,5]`
but when `k = 4`, nums is `[2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]`, which is what I wanted.
What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: Since you're copying from the vector into the vector, the vector is mutated and your iterators are invalidated.
Think that vector iterators are pretty much pointers - if you've changed the underlying array they now point to a different element

Comment: The above function works totally fine for me and gives me output as expected.

Comment: Which compiler? GCC gives your desired output for k = 2 and k = 4.

Comment: @SolvedGames "Expected/desired output" is the most dangerous demonstration of _undefined behavior_.

Comment: @WaisKamal I used clang 11 in LeetCode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `std::vector::insert` overload that you are using has a precondition that neither the second nor the third argument are iterators into the vector itself.

You are violating that precondition and therefore your program has undefined behavior.

Comment: I was trying to make this function with O(1) space complexity, and I didn't know that precondition. I'll try find different method. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @santaman The size complexity is linear in the number of inserted elements anyway, so you can just copy them into a temporary vector and insert from there. If you want to avoid the double copy you can resize the vector, move the upper range and then insert the new elements manually.